# Energy of 2 decayed particles with different masses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

Say, I started with a particle with mass M<sub>A</sub> at rest, and it decayed into another two particles with rest mass of M<sub>B</sub> and M<sub>C</sub>.

Ignoring binding energy, what is the energy of M<sub>B</sub> and M<sub>C</sub> (in the original reference frame, i.e. the zero-momentum frame)?

What I've attempted is to make use of the relativistic energy equation: $E^2=(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2$.  However, the equation became quite complicated, by which time I'm stuck (since my professor explicitly stated that it shouldn't have lengthy-algebra).

Comment: $m_a = m_b + m_c$ + the binding energy.  There is no general answer; each case will be different.

Comment: Hi, foxielmao! Welcome to Physics.SE. As the policy of the site goes, one is not supposed to show their ideas about the resolution of the question rather than just stating the question. I believe, especially when the question is of a rather algorithmic application of the laws in a situation than about the structure of the laws themselves. :-)

Comment: As far as the stated question goes, as @garyp has pointed out, it is not complete enough to yield a unique answer. One has to add parameters not specified in the question to formulate an expression that can be represented as the answer in one piece.

Comment: @Electrodynamist Sorry about that, I should have been more specific that binding energy is ignored in this context.  I will edit my question (along with adding some of the method I've used to try to solve the question).

Comment: The binding energy can be assumed to be equal to the mass difference, no problem there

Comment: Duplicate of [174263](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/174263/relativistic-kinematics-2-body-particle-decay?rq=1) .

Comment: Your professor was right. From conservation of energy, $M_A-E_B=E_C$, which, squared, yields $M_A^2-2M_A E_B=E_C^2-E_B^2=M_C^2-M_B^2$, so that $E_B=(M_A^2+ M_B^2-M_C^2)/(2M_A)$, and likewise for *C*, the textbook expression.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I understand your explanation, but I'm wondering doesn't $E^2$=$m^2$-$p^2$, so in the last line isn't the momentum part missing?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Oh I see now, the momentums cancels out.  Silly me.  Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Momentum is shared equally in magnitude but opposite in direction (conserved), from the mass lost.
Which can lead to widely varying velocities due to mass differences in the two particles.

so you have (with units such that $c=1$)

$$ P_{AorB}^2 =(M_A^2 - M_B^2 - M_C^2 )/4$$

Thus 
$$ E_B^2 = M_B^2 + P_{AorB}^2 = (M_A^2 + M_B^2 - M_C^2 )/4$$
$$ E_C^2 = M_C^2 + P_{AorB}^2 = (M_A^2 - M_B^2 + M_C^2 )/4$$

Comment: You are right it should be /4. Which now I retrospectively edited in. Good spot.

Comment: But... At threshold, *P* =0, for $M_B=M_C$, the daughter particle mass is still larger than half of the parent...        ***Can***   your first relation be sound?

Comment: if I put P=0 into the first equation I get $M_A^2=M_B^2+M_C^2$
its the energy that must equate, which is the square of mass?

Comment: So with your $M_B=M_C$ the daughter particle energy is exactly half the energy of the parent. What is the issue you have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50610/discussion-between-jmlcarter-and-cosmas-zachos).

Comment: @JMLCarter I think I want an expression of M<sub>B</sub> and M<sub>C</sub> to be the rest mass of particles B and C, whilst your expression is an expression indicating that M<sub>B</sub> and M<sub>C</sub> are not the rest masses.

Comment: The question stated "in the original reference frame, i.e. the zero-momentum frame" In this frame $M_B$ and $M_C$ would be moving (unless P=0). To translate from observed (relativisitic mass) to rest mass apply the gamma factor, this will move you to the frame fo reference of either $M_B$ or $M_C$ depending upon which factor you construct. Know how to do it?

Comment: one way to award a hat, I guess.